# implement regex to extract helpfull info from List

Tags: java, regex, list

I read lines of files to List

The contents of first file as follow:

```
2017-08-17 08:00:00 Comming in [Contact:NO] [REF:] [REF2:] [REF3:] [Name:+AA] [Fam:aa] [TEMP:-2:0:-2:0:-2] [Resident:9:free] [end:0:]
2017-08-18 09:00:00 ready now [Contact:NO] [REF:123] [REF2:] [REF3:] [Name:BB] [Fam:bb] [TEMP:-2:0:-2:0:-2] [Resident:138:booking] [end:0:] 
2017-08-19 010:00:00 Comming in [Contact:NO] [REF:] [REF2:] [REF3:] [Name:+AA] [Fam:aa] [TEMP:-2:0:-2:0:-2] [Resident:9:not booking] [end:0:]
2017-08-10 11:00:00 ready now [Contact:NO] [REF:123] [REF2:] [REF3:] [Name:BB] [Fam:bb] [TEMP:-2:0:-2:0:-2] [Resident:138:free] [end:0:]
```

the contents of second file as follow:

```
2017-08-20 12:00:00 Comming in [Contact:NO] [REF:] [REF2:] [REF3:] [Name:+AA] [Fam:aa] [TEMP:-2:0:-2:0:-2] [Resident:9:booking] [end:0:] 
2017-08-21 13:00:00 ready now [Contact:NO] [REF:123] [REF2:] [REF3:] [Name:BB] [Fam:bb] [TEMP:-2:0:-2:0:-2] [Resident:138:booking] [end:0:] 
2017-08-22 14:00:00 ready now [Contact:NO] [REF:123] [REF2:] [REF3:] [Name:AA] [Fam:bb] [TEMP:-2:0:-2:0:-2] [Resident:130:free] [end:0:]
2017-08-23 15:00:00 Comming in [Contact:NO] [REF:] [REF2:] [REF3:] [Name:+BB] [Fam:aa] [TEMP:-2:0:-2:0:-2] [Resident:9:booking] [end:0:]
2017-08-24 16:00:00 ready now [Contact:NO] [REF:123] [REF2:] [REF3:] [Name:AA] [Fam:bb] [TEMP:-2:0:-2:0:-2] [Resident:138:booking] [end:0:]
```

I use code in java to search in files and fetch each line has that values

This the first element of myList(its the contents of first file)

```
[
[
2017-08-17 08:00:00 Comming in [Contact:NO] [REF:] [REF2:] [REF3:] [Name:+AA] [Fam:aa] [TEMP:-2:0:-2:0:-2] [Resident:9:free] [end:0:], 
2017-08-18 09:00:00 ready now [Contact:NO] [REF:123] [REF2:] [REF3:] [Name:BB] [Fam:bb] [TEMP:-2:0:-2:0:-2] [Resident:138:booking] [end:0:], 
2017-08-19 010:00:00 Comming in [Contact:NO] [REF:] [REF2:] [REF3:] [Name:+AA] [Fam:aa] [TEMP:-2:0:-2:0:-2] [Resident:9:not booking] [end:0:],
2017-08-10 11:00:00 ready now [Contact:NO] [REF:123] [REF2:] [REF3:] [Name:BB] [Fam:bb] [TEMP:-2:0:-2:0:-2] [Resident:138:free] [end:0:]
],
```

and this the second element of myList(its the contents of second files)

```
[
2017-08-20 12:00:00 Comming in [Contact:NO] [REF:] [REF2:] [REF3:] [Name:+AA] [Fam:aa] [TEMP:-2:0:-2:0:-2] [Resident:9:booking] [end:0:], 
2017-08-21 13:00:00 ready now [Contact:NO] [REF:123] [REF2:] [REF3:] [Name:BB] [Fam:bb] [TEMP:-2:0:-2:0:-2] [Resident:138:booking] [end:0:], 
2017-08-22 14:00:00 ready now [Contact:NO] [REF:123] [REF2:] [REF3:] [Name:AA] [Fam:bb] [TEMP:-2:0:-2:0:-2] [Resident:130:free] [end:0:],
2017-08-23 15:00:00 Comming in [Contact:NO] [REF:] [REF2:] [REF3:] [Name:+BB] [Fam:aa] [TEMP:-2:0:-2:0:-2] [Resident:9:booking] [end:0:],
2017-08-24 16:00:00 ready now [Contact:NO] [REF:123] [REF2:] [REF3:] [Name:AA] [Fam:bb] [TEMP:-2:0:-2:0:-2] [Resident:138:booking] [end:0:]
]
]
```

I tried now to extract helpful info using this Regex from answer by [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45335683/java-read-lines-of-files-and-extract-only-the-helpfull-info)

```
^\[?(\d[\d: -]+\d).*?\[Name:(\w*)].*?\[Fam:(\w*)].*?\[Resident:\w*:([^\]]*)]
```

How to implement this regex in java to get each info:
**{note: the list some times is larger of that}**

```
the date and time
the name 
the fam
the resident
```

Comment: Now, you show more data, and the regex must be [`^\[*(\d[\d: -]+\d).*?\[Name:([^\]]*)].*?\[Fam:(\w*)].*?\[Resident:\w*:([^\]]*)]`](https://regex101.com/r/bmFO6R/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that result of list when print it manually using java

Comment: Please @WiktorStribizew How to apply java on this regex

Comment: Maybe https://ideone.com/5k1i8m will be enough for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the cod you provide extract only first four group how to loop through that list and extract each for example using replaceAll(regex,"$1"). Are you can guide me please

Comment: `for (String s: lst) { .... }`

Comment: I try with this but List<String> list = Arrays.asList(s);
        for (String str: list) 
        {
            System.out.println("--"+str.replaceAll(regex, "$1"));
        }

Comment: I already showed: use `Matcher` / `Pattern`. https://ideone.com/tv8SEi

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I updated my question

Comment: When reading files, you may parse the lines with regex at once, on the fly. Why read the lines into separate lists? I can't help further as I do not know what your final data structure should be. You may declare `List<String> datetimes = new ArrayList<>();`, `List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();`, `List<String> fams = new ArrayList<>();` and `List<String> residents = new ArrayList<>();` and add captured values there using `names.add(m.group(2));`... etc.

Comment: Yes @WiktorStribiżew that exactly what i expected thanks alot to your help.